# How to check if numbers in array are included in nested array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a tic-tac-toe game and want to check if player's choices match a nested array containing winning combinations.

At the moment, for example, [7,8,9] or [9,7,8] or [1,2,3] or [1,3,2] end the game and declare the winner, as they should.

However, for example, [1,7,8,6,9] or [1,7,3,5,6] or [1,4,2,3,9] are ignored and the winner won't be declared as intended, although the arrays include winning combinations "7,8,9" and "3,5,7" and "1,2,3".

Thank you for any advice or help in advance.

All winning combinations in a 3x3 grid.

```
WINNING_COMBOS = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
```

I have two player arrays, @@player_one and @@player_two that pick numbers from @possible_choice array.

```
@possible_choice = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
.
.
.
def player_one_turn()
  puts "Player One, make your choice:"
  p @possible_choice
  puts @grid
  @@player_one << @possible_choice.delete(gets.chomp.to_i)
  p @@player_one
end
```

I also have has_won? method

```
def has_won?
  WINNING_COMBOS.include?(@@player_one.sort) ||
  WINNING_COMBOS.include?(@@player_two.sort)
end
```

The unfinished game in its entirety. Please don't mind the grid, I'm still working on it.

```
class Grid
    WINNING_COMBOS = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
    attr_accessor :possible_choice
    attr_accessor :grid

    def initialize
        @possible_choice = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        @grid = "
                |----|----|----|   
                |  1 |  2 |  3 |
                |----|----|----|
                |  4 |  5 |  6 |
                |----|----|----|
                |  7 |  8 |  9 |
                |----|----|----|
                "
    end
end

class Game < Grid
    @@player_one = Array.new
    @@player_two = Array.new

    def game
        puts
        puts "*** This is a tic-tac-toe game for two human players. ***"
        puts
        loop do
            player_one_turn()
            puts
                if has_won?
                    puts "The game has ended. Player One has won!"
                    puts
                    return
                end
            break if @@player_one.length == 5
            player_two_turn()
            puts
                if has_won?
                    puts "The game has ended. Player Two has won!"
                    puts
                    return
                end
        end
    end

    def player_one_turn()
        puts "Player One, make your choice:"
        p @possible_choice
        puts @grid
        @@player_one << @possible_choice.delete(gets.chomp.to_i)
        p @@player_one
    end

    def player_two_turn()
        puts "Player Two, make your choice:"
        p @possible_choice
        puts @grid
        @@player_two << @possible_choice.delete(gets.chomp.to_i)
        p @@player_two
    end

    def has_won?
        WINNING_COMBOS.include?(@@player_one.sort) ||
        WINNING_COMBOS.include?(@@player_two.sort)
    end
end

new_game = Game.new
new_game.game
```

Comment: `WINNING_COMBOS.any? { |e| (@@player_one.sort & e).size == 3 }` → you need to ensure that there is an element in winnings, that is fully intersected with a player’s moves.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to have a single 3×3 grid where each field can either be empty, `X` or `O`? The two `@@player_one` / `@@player_two` arrays seem a bit redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest I can think of is:

```
def has_won?(player)
  WINNING_COMBOS.any? { |combo| (player & combo).size == combo.size }
end
```

However, if you where to use [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) instead of [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html) you could do with the following:

```
def has_won?(player)
  WINNING_COMBOS.any? { |combo| combo <= player } # check for subset
end
```

To convert the `WINNING_COMBOS` to sets simply do the following:

```
require 'set'

WINNING_COMBOS = [
  [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],
  [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
  [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]
].map(&:to_set)

# for players use
@@player_one = Set.new
```

Comment: Typo alert: one too many "h"'s. Will delete this comment. Consider `WINNING_COMBOS = Set.new([[1,2,3],....])`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was really helpful. I hadn't learned about Sets yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
WINNING_COMBOS = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]

def win?(player)
  WINNING_COMBOS.each do |x,z,y|
    return true if player.include?(x) && player.include?(z) && player.include?(y) 
  end
  false
end

def has_won?
  win?(@@player_one) || win?(@@player_two)
end
```

Should do the work, there is no need to sort an array.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to use `return true if ...` instead of `true if ...`, otherwise `win?` would always return `false`. If you replace `each` with `any?` there is no need for `true if`, only the statement that follows it and you're able to leave out `false` at the end.

Comment: @3limin4t0r made a good suggestion that you acknowledged. So why not edit your answer? You may have noticed that some members acknowledge contributions in edited answers; others acknowledge in a comment, as you have done, to keep the answer "clean". (I'm in the latter camp.) Also, when editing, I suggest you remove what you had before (and make no reference to it, and no "Edit:", please), just as you would if you were writing an article or book.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland would be more than glad to do it if I know how :)

Comment: Great solution. It's so simple yet I couldn't figure it out! Thank you all for helping me out.